# Usage of "I am done"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, participial-adjectives

Why is *I am reached incorrect* while *I am done* is correct?

Ex: *I reached office at 9am today* is correct while *I am reached at 9am* is incorrect.

But *I am done with this project* is correct. Can someone please explain me the difference here?

Comment: Note the word "explain" is followed by the thing that you are explaining. So you should say "explain the difference to me"

Comment: @JamesK: your comment raises an interesting point. "give the book to me" -> "give me the book": why can't "explain the difference to me" become "explain me the difference"? Because **give** is ditransitive- it can take two objects- and **explain** is not. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/give

Answer (score 1):

**did** and **reached** are both past forms: they can be used to make a simple past sentence:

> I reached the office
>   I did my homework

**done** and **reached** are both past participle forms. You can use a past participle to form one of the three perfect tenses:

> I had reached the office...
>   I have reached the office...
>   I will have reached the office...

You can also use a past participle of a transitive verb to form a passive voice sentence:

> I reach him - *active voice*
>   He is reached - *passive voice*
>   He is reached by me - *passive voice*

Note that the object **him** of the active voice sentence becomes the patient **he** in the passive voice sentence, and the subject **I** either disappears or becomes the agent attached with **by**

Looking at your two sentences:

> I reached the office at 9am  
>   I am reached at 9am

In the first sentence, **reached** is the past form of reach. The sentence is past simple, active mood, with **I** as the subject - I reached the office.

In the second sentence, **reached** is a past participle form of reach. The sentence is simple present, passive mood, with **I** as the patient- something reached me. It sounds strange to use simple present to describe an event that happened in the past, but this technique is a perfectly acceptable narrative style.

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but the meaning of the second version is probably not what you intended.

If you look at the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/done) entry for **done**, you will find that it can be both a verb-form and an adjective. The reason that you can use **I am done** without switching to passive voice is that **done** can be used as an adjective. Here is a definition of the adjective form:

> If something is done, or you are done with it, it is finished, or you have finished doing, using it, etc.

If you look in the same dictionary for [reached](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reach?q=reached), you will find that there is no adjective form.